# Mysql and PHP Result is okay but login incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I have mysql connection and its working. Connection is done and mysql result its okay. Im trying to login my panel but everytime giving "password is incorrect"/Kullanıcı adınız veya şifreniz yanlış. How can i fix this?

```
if(@$_GET['selection'] == 'verification' ) 
    {
        $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
        $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
        $tbl_name="kullanicilar";
        $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM kullanicilar WHERE kullaniciadi='$myusername' and sifre='$mypassword'";
        $result=@mysql_query($sql);
        $count=@mysql_num_rows($result);
        if (@mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
        {
            session_register("myusername");
            session_register("mypassword");
            header("location:index.php?page=giris&lang=tr&selection=verified");
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Kullanici adiniz veya sifreniz yanlis. <b>$count</b>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: are you storing your passwords in plaintext? provide us the database structure and the html form structure

Comment: remove the @ and see if an error is generated, may give you more info.  You may also want to do a select from the table without the WHERE clauses, and iterate through the comparison, outputting the result along the way... could be you simply are not matching the strings.

Comment: you also may want to reconsider passing around the password in the session, unless you are hashing somewhere and not showing us.

Comment: Dont giving a error @Dave

im using WAMPP final version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

1. Use $count in the 'if' condition instead of calling mysql_num_rows function again. Each mysql function call is an expense you want to avoid.
2. Try the code by commenting "stripslashes" lines.
3. Echo and get the query. Then run the query directly without this script (like in SQLYog or in phpMyAdmin) and see if it gives you the result.